# single sample gene set enrichment analysis: R scripts not working

Tags: r

I am trying to run single sample gene set enrichment analysis (ssGSEA), which is a program from the Broad Institute. They have published an R script for running the program easily in R or R studio. I downloaded the folder from Github, and tried executing the scripts, but it is not working.
This is the wrapper script:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env Rscript
options( warn = -1 )

suppressPackageStartupMessages( if(!require("pacman")) install.packages ("pacman") )
suppressPackageStartupMessages(p_load("optparse"))

# parse the directory this file is located
script.dir <- commandArgs()[4]
script.dir <- sub('^(.*(/|\\\\)).*', '\\1', sub('.*?\\=','', script.dir))
# this doesn't seem to be reliably working on Windows OS
# if called from the directory is 'ssgsea-cli.R' resides in
# the line below attempts to fix this
script.dir <- ifelse(dir.exists(script.dir), script.dir, '.')

# specify command line arguments
option_list <- list(
  make_option( c("-i", "--input"), action='store', type='character',  dest='input_ds', help='Path to input GCT file.'),
  make_option( c("-o", "--ouptut"), action='store', type='character',  dest='output_prefix', help='File prefix for output files.', default='out'),
  make_option( c("-d", "--db"), action='store', type='character',  dest='gene_set_databases', help='Path to gene set database (GMT format).'),
  make_option( c("-n", "--norm"), action='store', type='character',  dest='sample_norm_type', help='Sample normalization: "rank", "log", "log.rank" or "none".', default = 'rank'),
  make_option( c("-w", "--weight"), action='store', type='character',  dest='weight', help='When weight==0, all genes have the same weight; if weight>0 actual values matter and can change the resulting score.', default = 0.75),
  make_option( c("-c", "--correl"), action='store', type='character',  dest='correl_type', help='Correlation type: "rank", "z.score", "symm.rank".', default = 'z.score'),
  make_option( c("-t", "--test"), action='store', type='character',  dest='statistic', help='Test statistic: "area.under.RES", "Kolmogorov-Smirnov"', default = 'area.under.RES'),
  make_option( c("-s", "--score"), action='store', type='character',  dest='output_score_type', help='Score type: "ES" - enrichment score,  "NES" - normalized ES', default = 'NES'),
  make_option( c("-p", "--perm"), action='store', type='character',  dest='nperm', help='Number of permutations', default = 1000),
  make_option( c("-m", "--minoverlap"), action='store', type='character',  dest='min_overlap', help='Minimal overlap between signature and data set.', default = 10),
  make_option( c("-x", "--extendedoutput"), action='store', type='character',  dest='extended_output', help='If TRUE additional stats on signature coverage etc. will be included as row annotations in the GCT results files.', default = TRUE),
  make_option( c("-e", "--export"), action='store', type='character',  dest='export_signat_gct', help='For each signature export expression GCT files.', default = TRUE),
  make_option( c("-g", "--globalfdr"), action='store', type='character',  dest='global_fdr', help='If TRUE global FDR across all data columns is calculated.', default = FALSE),
  make_option( c("-l", "--lightspeed"), action='store', type='character',  dest='multi_core', help='If TRUE processing will be parallized across gene sets. (I ran out of single letters to define parameters...)', default = TRUE),
  make_option( c("-y", "--yaml"), action='store', type='character',  dest='yaml_file', help='Parameter file (.yaml)', default = NA)
)

## #####################################
## source the actual script
source(file.path(script.dir, 'src', 'ssGSEA2.0.R'))
source(file.path(script.dir, 'src', 'parse_yaml_ssgsea.R'))

# parse command line parameters
opt <- parse_param_ssgsea(option_list) 
 
# hard-coded parameters
spare.cores <- 0 # use all available cpus
log.file <- paste(opt$output_prefix, '_ssgsea.log.txt', sep='')


## ######################################################################################################
##
##                   run ssGSEA
##
## ######################################################################################################
res <- ssGSEA2(
    input.ds=opt$input_ds,
    output.prefix=opt$output_prefix,
    gene.set.databases=opt$gene_set_databases,
  sample.norm.type=opt$sample_norm_type,
    weight=opt$weight,
    statistic=opt$statistic,
    output.score.type=opt$output_score_type,
    nperm=opt$nperm,
    min.overlap=opt$min_overlap,
  correl.type=opt$correl_type,
    export.signat.gct=opt$export_signat_gct,
    extended.output=opt$extended_output,
    global.fdr=opt$global_fdr,
  par=opt$multi_core,
  spare.cores=spare.cores,
  log.file=log.file
)
```

The working directory of my project file is set to the folder with all of the source files that I downloaded from Github, and when I run the `ssgsea-cli.R` script, i get the following errors:

```
> #!/usr/bin/env Rscript
> options( warn = -1 )
Warning message:
In normalizePath(dirname(f)) : path[1]="NA": No such file or directory
> 
> suppressPackageStartupMessages( if(!require("pacman")) install.packages ("pacman") )
> suppressPackageStartupMessages(p_load("optparse"))
> 
> # parse the directory this file is located
> script.dir <- commandArgs()[4]
> script.dir <- sub('^(.*(/|\\\\)).*', '\\1', sub('.*?\\=','', script.dir))
> # this doesn't seem to be reliably working on Windows OS
> # if called from the directory is 'ssgsea-cli.R' resides in
> # the line below attempts to fix this
> script.dir <- ifelse(dir.exists(script.dir), script.dir, '.')
> 
> # specify command line arguments
> option_list <- list(
+     make_option( c("-i", "--input"), action='store', type='character',  dest='input_ds', help='Path to input GCT file.'),
+     make_option( c("-o", "--ouptut"), action='store', type='character',  dest='output_prefix', help='File prefix for output files.', default='out'),
+     make_option( c("-d", "--db"), action='store', type='character',  dest='gene_set_databases', help='Path to gene set database (GMT format).'),
+     make_option( c("-n", "--norm"), action='store', type='character',  dest='sample_norm_type', help='Sample normalization: "rank", "log", "log.rank" or "none".', default = 'rank'),
+     make_option( c("-w", "--weight"), action='store', type='character',  dest='weight', help='When weight==0, all genes have the same weight; if weight>0 actual values matter and can change the resulting score.', default = 0.75),
+     make_option( c("-c", "--correl"), action='store', type='character',  dest='correl_type', help='Correlation type: "rank", "z.score", "symm.rank".', default = 'z.score'),
+     make_option( c("-t", "--test"), action='store', type='character',  dest='statistic', help='Test statistic: "area.under.RES", "Kolmogorov-Smirnov"', default = 'area.under.RES'),
+     make_option( c("-s", "--score"), action='store', type='character',  dest='output_score_type', help='Score type: "ES" - enrichment score,  "NES" - normalized ES', default = 'NES'),
+     make_option( c("-p", "--perm"), action='store', type='character',  dest='nperm', help='Number of permutations', default = 1000),
+     make_option( c("-m", "--minoverlap"), action='store', type='character',  dest='min_overlap', help='Minimal overlap between signature and data set.', default = 10),
+     make_option( c("-x", "--extendedoutput"), action='store', type='character',  dest='extended_output', help='If TRUE additional stats on signature coverage etc. will be included as row annotations in the GCT results files.', default = TRUE),
+     make_option( c("-e", "--export"), action='store', type='character',  dest='export_signat_gct', help='For each signature export expression GCT files.', default = TRUE),
+     make_option( c("-g", "--globalfdr"), action='store', type='character',  dest='global_fdr', help='If TRUE global FDR across all data columns is calculated.', default = FALSE),
+     make_option( c("-l", "--lightspeed"), action='store', type='character',  dest='multi_core', help='If TRUE processing will be parallized across gene sets. (I ran out of single letters to define parameters...)', default = TRUE),
+     make_option( c("-y", "--yaml"), action='store', type='character',  dest='yaml_file', help='Parameter file (.yaml)', default = NA)
+ )
> 
> ## #####################################
> ## source the actual script
> source(file.path(script.dir, 'src', 'ssGSEA2.0.R'))
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
> source(file.path(script.dir, 'src', 'parse_yaml_ssgsea.R'))
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
> 
> # parse command line parameters
> opt <- parse_param_ssgsea(option_list) 
Error in parse_param_ssgsea(option_list) : 
  could not find function "parse_param_ssgsea"
> 
> # hard-coded parameters
> spare.cores <- 0 # use all available cpus
> log.file <- paste(opt$output_prefix, '_ssgsea.log.txt', sep='')
Error in paste(opt$output_prefix, "_ssgsea.log.txt", sep = "") : 
  object 'opt' not found
> 
> 
> ## ######################################################################################################
> ##
> ##                   run ssGSEA
> ##
> ## ######################################################################################################
> res <- ssGSEA2(
+     input.ds=opt$input_ds,
+     output.prefix=opt$output_prefix,
+     gene.set.databases=opt$gene_set_databases,
+     sample.norm.type=opt$sample_norm_type,
+     weight=opt$weight,
+     statistic=opt$statistic,
+     output.score.type=opt$output_score_type,
+     nperm=opt$nperm,
+     min.overlap=opt$min_overlap,
+     correl.type=opt$correl_type,
+     export.signat.gct=opt$export_signat_gct,
+     extended.output=opt$extended_output,
+     global.fdr=opt$global_fdr,
+     par=opt$multi_core,
+     spare.cores=spare.cores,
+     log.file=log.file
+ )
Error in ssGSEA2(input.ds = opt$input_ds, output.prefix = opt$output_prefix,  : 
  could not find function "ssGSEA2"
```

> 

When I run `ssgsea-cli.R --help` in Terminal, the command is not found. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this work? MacOS and yes, I have QUARTZ

https://github.com/broadinstitute/ssGSEA2.0

Comment: you're using the command line interface version of the script, what is the terminal command you are using

Comment: @rawr the web-based instructions just say to run `ssgsea-cli.R --help` in terminal for more instructions... so i guess ssgsea-cli.R is the command?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/broadinstitute/ssGSEA2.0#r-gui--rstudio) a bit, maybe you need to run  `ssgsea-gui.R` not `ssgsea-cli.R`?